# Constants for AVCaptureMetadataOutput's metadataObjectTypes property?

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, constants

When using AVFoundation to detect features (e.g. faces or barcodes) in an image, you must call a line such as:

```
AVCaptureMetadataOutput *metadataOutput = ...;
metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = metadataOutput.availableMetadataObjectTypes;
```

Examining availableMetadataObjectTypes shows the following strings:

```
face,
"org.gs1.UPC-E",
"org.iso.Code39",
"org.iso.Code39Mod43",
"org.gs1.EAN-13",
"org.gs1.EAN-8",
"com.intermec.Code93",
"org.iso.Code128",
"org.iso.PDF417",
"org.iso.QRCode",
"org.iso.Aztec"
```

If I am writing a barcode scanning app, I don't want the framework to be looking for faces, so instead of passing `metadataOutput.availableMetadataObjectTypes`, I want to pass specific barcodes to look for. Rather than using these hard-coded strings, I was hoping they were defined as constants somewhere.

Do they exist anywhere in the framework, or must I use hard-coded strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are constants for the various barcode types, just in the `AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject` class ([full list here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

So you can do something like this:

```
metadataOutput.metadataObjectType = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code];
```