# React Native Camera Barcode Types

Tags: react-native, qr-code, barcode-scanner, react-native-camera

I'm trying to use `react-native-camera@0.4.1` (with `react-native@0.39.2`) to create a QR code scanner. The relevant essentials of my `render()` method are:

```
<Camera 
  aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}
  onBarCodeRead={(data) => console.log(data)} 
  barCodeTypes={['qr']}>
</Camera>
```

Without the `barCodeTypes` prop, everything works as expected. But once I include it, the view does not render, and I get the following error message:

```
*** -[AVCaptureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes:] Unsupported type found
    - use -availableMetadataObjectTypes
```

I'm guessing that I just need to write my `['qr']` argument in some other and correct way, but I'm not able to find any information in the [documentation](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I found [another post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187919/constants-for-avcapturemetadataoutputs-metadataobjecttypes-property) that helped me figure out the availableMetadataObjectTypes. So to fix my particular problem, I'll just be changing `barCodeTypes={['qr']}` to `barCodeTypes={['org.iso.QRCode']}`.

Answer (score 2):

It should be changed to

`barCodeTypes={[RNCamera.Constants.BarCodeType.qr]}`